# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de un campo desde una tabla anidada en Power M Code?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

Tengo unas tablas anidadas en Power Query. Cada tabla agrupa por mes y extrae los días hábiles. El campo `[Monthly Target]` contiene el valor de la meta de ventas por mes. Me gustaría poder dividir este valor por la cuenta de `número de días hábiles` y así obtener la meta diaria en el campo `[Target]`.

El problema es que no sé cómo llamar un valor en particular en un campo desde una tabla anidada.

Esto es lo que he tratado hasta ahora:

1. Use la función `Table.RowCount()` para contar el número de filas:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/Table.RowCount(_))})
   ```

> Error: We cannot apply operator / to types Number and Function.

[image]

2. Hice una lista anidada y extraje por el el valor máximo usando la función `List.Max()`:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each [GroupIndex]})

   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/List.Max(Test2))})
   ```

> Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type List.

[image]

3. Similar al paso anterior extraje el máximo `List.Max()` y luego use el resultado para la división:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each List.Max([GroupIndex])})
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/Test2)})
   ```

> Error: We cannot apply operator / to types Number and Table.

[image]

Me gustaría realizar la división antes de expandir todas las tablas.

Aprecio cualquier ayuda. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para futuras referencias **Imke Feldmann** de otro foro me dio esta respuesta y funciono perfectamente!

Me dice que no puedo utilizar el comando `each` dos veces en una función en su lugar la sintaxis se debe anidar en este caso usando (inner) como se muestra en la linea de código.

Hi David,

You cannot use the "each"-keyword twice in one command. Instead use the standard-function-syntax like this:

```
=Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", (inner) => inner[Monthly Target]/Table.RowCount(_))})
```